# XGrabKeyboard only blocks the keyboard while the program is running

Tags: c++, linux, qt, x11

I'm writing a code to get the pressed key and block the keyboard input. Example: If the Super_L or Super_R key is pressed, prevent them to open a application menu. The code works while the program is opened, but when the program is closed the keys are sent to system. Example: If user press the Super_L key nothing happens while the program is running but when the program is closed, automatically the Ubuntu application menu is opened. How can i fix this issue?

```
void hook()
{
    Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(0);
    XEvent ev;

    if(!dpy)
    {
        qDebug() << "Error";
        return;
    }

    XGrabKeyboard(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), false, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, CurrentTime);

    forever
    {
        XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);
        switch (ev.type)
        {
        case KeyPress:
            qDebug() << "KeyPress" << XKeysymToString(XKeycodeToKeysym(dpy, ev.xkey.keycode, 0));
            break;
        case KeyRelease:
            qDebug() << "KeyRelease" << XKeysymToString(XKeycodeToKeysym(dpy, ev.xkey.keycode, 0));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoth [the manual](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/close-operation.html):

> When the X server's connection to a client is closed either by an
>   explicit call to `XCloseDisplay()` or by a process that exits, the X
>   server performs the following automatic operations:
>
> - It disowns all selections owned by the client (see    `XSetSelectionOwner()`).
> - It performs an `XUngrabPointer()` and `XUngrabKeyboard()` if the client    has actively grabbed the pointer or the keyboard.
> - It performs an `XUngrabServer()` if the client has grabbed the server.
> - It releases all passive grabs made by the client.

Grabs are requested by clients and granted to clients. For the duration of a grab, all relevant events are delivered to the grabbing client. No client, no grab.

I don't see what's to fix here. If you want a piece of functionality working, make sure the application that implements it is running.

Answer (score 1):

From `man XGetKeyboard`:

> The X server automatically performs an UngrabKeyboard request if the event window for an active keyboard grab becomes not viewable.

That is by design. Otherwise the keyboard could be left grabbed indefinitely by a defunct application, and that would not be appreciated by the user. Granted, the window is still viewable (it's the root window) but the display connection is closed, so the rationale is the same.

If your application needs to keep the grab even after closing... well, you will have to stay in the background without actually quitting.

Comment: Ok "The X server automatically performs an UngrabKeyboard request if the event window for an active keyboard grab becomes not viewable." but why the pressed keys when the program is running are fired when the program closes?